# Why is iTerm2 pinging faster than Terminal?

Tags: terminal, iterm, ping

I am using `ping www.google.com` from Terminal and iTerm2. iTerm reports faster responses from Google. Why is that? Is there a more efficient way of understanding how my connection is doing?

[image: iterm2 vs terminal in a ping battle to get to google.com]

Comment: There should be no difference. Note that they're also showing different `ttl` values, suggesting they're using different routes to the destination. Are these running simultaneously? Are they using the same `ping` binary with the same options (if you're using zsh, try `whence foo` to see what it's executing; if you're using bash, try `type ping`)? Are they actually pinging the same destination IP number?

Comment: They don’t run different versions of `ping`.  Start by pinging something locally like your router and see if there is a difference